# ASP Disable button and run function

Tags: asp-classic

I want a webpage that will disable a button and run the function, after the page is refreshed the button will be re-enabled. The button are created with the method below. The problem is when I click on the button, it can disable but it wont runs the function, the page won't even refresh. No idea where the problem arise from.

`set common = server.createobject("Pen_Ebizcommonproc.stringproc")`

`<%=common.writeButton ("Submit1","Submit","Create New Sales Contract",30,"onclick=""this.disabled=true;CheckGWidth(this.form);this.form.ContractType.value='N';""")%>`

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Is the form submitted? Do you even have a form? Also, please post the generated markup of the button maybe it's not a submit button at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I managed to solve the problem. Once again thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do mostly is extract it in a javascript function. 
I remember that disabling a button cancels any following inline action of that button.

```
<form action="test.asp" method="post">
    <input type="submit" onclick="doSomething(this);" />
    <input type="text" id="ContractType" name="ContractType" />
</form>
```

Then in the javascript

```
function doSomething(sender)
{
    sender.disabled=true;
    CheckGWidth(sender.form);
    sender.form.ContractType.value='N';
    sender.form.submit();
}
```

Hope this is of any help.

Comment: Well, what I did was to add form1.submit() into the onClick. As it is also similar to sender.form.submit() in the solution provided by you. Regarding submit(), best guess is that if we disable the button and then run the function (client side validation), server side validation will not run because of the button disabled. So Submit() will force it to pass the data to the server from client side again. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I believe you are right. A disabled button works as a "return false;" thus canceling any further *client side* action.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to do this a few time so that refreshing a page and revisiting a page is treated differently to one's first visit or after submitting one part of a form when there are more than one forms on a page, like when calculating updates for a shopping cart.

Depending on the scenario I used cookies to record the page loaded so that I could detect if it was the first visit, a refresh or what. If you have two buttons for things like "update" or "finish" they can use seperate forms with different hidden fields for mode=update or mode=finish.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. But I manage to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: How come I use it on all our order forms where the user first calculates quantity discount? I also use it in the custom built shopping carts on a several other sites.

Comment: I just read your response, and please don't take any offence but I'd like to say that your construction would fail if the visitor had cookies disabled. I would personally use the Session variable and/or database records instead. Never rely on something that can be disabled :)

Comment: Yes the session variable might work every time, but I still use cookies because if cookies are disabled or not supported then the user is of the type that cannot benefit from the functions that are available anyway. In fact I use lots of different criteria to weed out real people from bots because in some sections, especially our order pages, honesty is the key.